# I am not getting the proper data from Rest API

Tags: node.js, rest

I am not getting proper data from an REST API in *node.js*. I've included example data below. How can I get data as key and value from the data?

Example data:

```
{"GetFundListResult":"[{\"Fcode\":\"F0075\",\"name\":\"Axis Mutual Fund\"},
{\"Fcode\":\"F0003\",\"name\":\"Birla Sunlife Mutual Fund\"},
{\"Fcode\":\"F0007\",\"name\":\"DSP BlackRock Mutual Fund\"},
{\"Fcode\":\"F0032\",\"name\":\"Franklin Templeton Mutual Fund\"},
{\"Fcode\":\"F0014\",\"name\":\"HDFC Mutual Fund\"},
{\"Fcode\":\"F0025\",\"name\":\"ICICI Prudential Mutual Fund\"}]"}
```

My Code -

```
var GetFundListResult = data.GetFundListResult;      
for(var row in GetFundListResult ){              
    console.log("data:", GetFundListResult[row]);
}
```

My output data (I am getting single characters in each loop):

```
data: [
data: {
data: "
data: F
data: c
data: o
data: d
data: e
data: "
data: :
data: "
data: F
data: 0
data: 0
data: 7
data: 5
data: "
data: ,
data: "
data: n
data: a
data: m
data: e
data: "
data: :
data: "
data: A
data: x
data: i
data: s
data:  
data: M
data: u
data: t
data: u
data: a
data: l
```

The fix is probably trivial, but I am unable to see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing the output in JSON as the response/output looks like JSON.

```
var GetFundListResult = data.GetFundListResult;

for( var row in GetFundListResult ){    
var json = JSON.parse(row);
console.log( data: json);
}
```